# Css :last-child and ::after

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I would like to visually separate the last icon with class "delimiter" with the other ones.
In this case, first 3 icons should be black and the last 2 grey, and between is delimiter "|".
Can I accomplish this with the combination of :last-child and ::after?

```
<div class="content">
  <i class="fa fa-square delimiter" />
  <i class="fa fa-square delimiter" />
  <i class="fa fa-square delimiter" />
  <i class="fa fa-square" />
  <i class="fa fa-square" />
</div>


// css
.content i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.content i.delimiter {
  color: #000;
}


.content i.delimiter:last-child::after {
  content: '|';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: goldenrod;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;;
  left: 24px;;
}
```

Comment: last-child is an element selector - it only works at an elemental level, not a class level - so the last child would be the last `i`, not the last `.delimiter`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/Ln4a7wq2/1/ is this right, as Pete said?

Comment: On a separate note, if you only want the pipe after the third item, then why not just give it a different class?

Comment: change the rule to `.content i:not(.delimiter):first-child::after`